# help me in codes of notepad++

Tags: php, html, notepad++

im a beginner in learning PHP, im starting with HTML in notepad++, i wrote some codes to creat a simple table, but i dont know how to run it and what s wrong .

Answer (score 4):

A web browser can't run/execute PHP by itself, you need a webserver with PHP capabilities.

A very easy way to get started with this on windows is to install [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html). It's easy to install and comes with tons of documentation.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>Open the saved file with a browser.</strike>

EDIT: My mistake, it was late at night yesterday: you do need more than a web browser to run php (something I took for granted since I use OS X and had enabled things a while back)

but if it's just html a web browser is fine, but it doesn't hurt to get php capability ahead of time.

Comment: FYI, another reason I just said that was because novin mentioned "im starting with HTML"

Comment: So, are you using OS X or not? Notepad++ is a Windows app.

Comment: I use both OSes...